# Shape-outside property shows the right shape, but not forms text

Tags: html, css

```css
div{
    width: calc(5vw + 2.8868vh);
    height: 100vh;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    transform-origin: left;
    transform: skewX(30deg) translateX(-28vh) scaleX(10);
    float: left;
    shape-outside: polygon(0vh 0vh, calc(50vw - 38vh) 0vh, calc(50vw + 20vh) 100vh, 0vh 100vh);
}
p{
    word-spacing: 0.9em;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-size: 150%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    float: right;
    width: 70vw;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent quis iaculis dui, quis dignissim nisi. Pellentesque ac leo neque. Nunc sit amet sollicitudin ligula, in viverra mauris. Nunc viverra mollis erat luctus blandit. Nam pharetra libero et molestie dignissim. Aliquam non mollis mauris. Donec id risus odio. Sed tempus, leo a iaculis iaculis, orci ipsum porttitor ex, in mattis odio massa at ante. Maecenas sit amet finibus lectus. Mauris convallis ullamcorper facilisis. Integer elit augue, finibus sed maximus vel, feugiat vitae tellus. Integer lobortis ultricies massa sit amet porta. Etiam erat ante, pulvinar id nulla in, ultricies consequat urna.
</p>
```

I did all the research I can, I tried to delete, add or replace any of the properties above, but it isn't working. Transform isn't the reason, the shape-outside shape according to Devtools is the right shape, positions don't matter, the width or height of the text doesn't do nothing, so I need your help now. What's the problem?

Comment: I'm not quite sure i understand what's the problem here

Comment: Because of the shape-outside, the text should follow the angle of the element shown above as div. But the text goes in a straight line. Read about shape-outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angle you're talking about is shown by the transform property also you don't need to float the `p` to the right otherwise the text will go to the right and no text will rub against the div,also your polygon syntax is wrong.

I commented out the unnecessary lines of code

```css
div {
  width: calc(5vw + 2.8868vh);
  height: 100vh;
  /*     background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8); */
  /*     transform-origin: left; */
  /*     transform: skewX(30deg) translateX(-28vh) scaleX(10); */
  float: left;
  shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 10% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

p {
  word-spacing: 0.9em;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 150%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  /*     float: right; */
  width: 70vw;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent quis iaculis dui, quis dignissim nisi. Pellentesque ac leo neque. Nunc sit amet sollicitudin ligula, in viverra mauris. Nunc viverra mollis erat luctus blandit. Nam pharetra libero et molestie
  dignissim. Aliquam non mollis mauris. Donec id risus odio. Sed tempus, leo a iaculis iaculis, orci ipsum porttitor ex, in mattis odio massa at ante. Maecenas sit amet finibus lectus. Mauris convallis ullamcorper facilisis. Integer elit augue, finibus
  sed maximus vel, feugiat vitae tellus. Integer lobortis ultricies massa sit amet porta. Etiam erat ante, pulvinar id nulla in, ultricies consequat urna. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
  et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
  occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
```

I'll leave re shaping the polygon to you might wanna consider using this [Tool](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/)